# want to catch a window change event in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to detect when any notification of any app comes in. 
I was looking for a sort of "window will open" event, to detect when the notification window pops up, but as far as I can see there is no such thing.

Would it be possible to use the "viewWillStartLiveResize" in some way or another for this purpose ? 
Or is there any other way to detect a screen change event?

Comment: mission impossible.

Answer (score 0):

[viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) or [traitCollectionDidChange:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITraitEnvironment/traitCollectionDidChange:) should be enough to detect app screen size change (especially on an ipad split mode). But in your case that's not possible - you have an access to your and only your app views hierarchy. Push notification windows pops up over your app on a springboard view hierarchy. So as notification center, etc. They just don't resize your app's window, they overlap it.